# View images in 360 degrees

Tags: php, flash, apache-flex, actionscript-3, actionscript

I would like to rotate an image in 360 degrees, like [**this site**](http://www.big360.in/).

I have a site, where the users can upload images and view them in 360 degrees. 
Please advice me how to achieve this.

Comment: Basically you need a Flash 3D panorama viewer. If you can find one that accepts image name as a Flashvar you're good. To create panoramic images you need a panorama editing (*stitching*) software.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [Papervision3D](http://code.google.com/p/papervision3d/downloads/detail?name=Papervision3D_1_5.zip&can=2&q=) to achieve things similar to that link you provided. You can [get started here](http://pv3d.org/).

If you have concerns about the learning curve for Papervision, you can download already made applications that are very similar to what you want. I recommend taking a look around [ActiveDen](http://activeden.net/category/flash/image-viewers). [Here's one I found](http://activeden.net/item/interactive-renders-360-deg-3d-object-rotator/39718).

Comment: Well, i just meant, how can i include this functionality once i have an image in my php site. I would like to enable the users to view the image in 360 degrees. See my edited question.

Comment: You'll have to embed a SWF that you've created using Flash onto your website, then parse through FlashVars a URL to the image you want to display.

Comment: I am looking for an example of rotating the image not only along the x-axis, but also along the y-axis.

Comment: If you have at least an intermediate knowledge of ActionScript 3, you'll be able to create this quite easily using some of the beginners tutorials on Papervision3D.

Answer (score 3):

user jquery you can also integrate this with php

http://www.openstudio.fr/jquery-virtual-tour/

http://jquery.vostrel.cz/reel#demo

http://www.ajax-zoom.com/examples/example15.php

http://www.openstudio.fr/jquery.spherical.panorama/

Comment: The last link that you gave is very nice... but i am actually looking for a flex solution.

Answer (score 1):

Basically best 360 degree viewer is just an image loader application that loads a series of images you took (png format) and then swap based on user input, it will show the correct image frame

This solution works best as it allow image pre-processing, faster rendering (and much more beautiful than using 3D engines). The more images you used, to smoother scrolling effects. You will not need to have a 3D model, all 360 product viewers doing this way. The back side effects is loading images cost time and you will need to prepare the image series then.

========== EDIT ===========

I've made a mistake in a hurry :D, the thing you specified is not 360 product view, it's called panorama, you will need to have 6 images captured and used a 3D engine to achieve this effect. Basically it will wrap your 6 images in to a cube then allow you to rotate the camera around to view it.